# How do I disable dates in asp .net textbox textmode = date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm having this issue where I want to set disable on the dates in the textbox with the textmode = date. I would prefer it to be done in c#.
Any advice?
Here is the aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="tbStartDate_TextChanged" 
TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the C# file

```
protected void disablePastDateintextbox()
{
   ????????
}
```

Comment: what Problem you get..?? I think you can do something like textboxid.enable=false in page load event

Comment: there isn't any problem but I would like to disable some dates in the textbox.

Comment: by doing your suggested method, it actually disable the whole textbox.

Comment: @StevenMeowDeClaude please put an example

Comment: @Sachu i have added in the example.

Comment: @StevenMeowDeClaude at what condition you need to make the textbox as readonly

Comment: @Sachu Hi, the textmode = date <-- this like an datepicker. I dont want to set readonly or disable the whole textbox. I'm looking for ways to disable selection to the past dates in the textbox. that's the condition.

Comment: @StevenMeowDeClaude ok understand dont allow user to select past days..for that you can write a script and check whether user selected date is less than current date..if so give an error and dont allow to submit..comment back if this is ur requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77780/discussion-between-sachu-and-steven-meow-de-claude).

Comment: @Sachu thanks for replying. I'm hope to achieve this upon on page load. Which means remove additional validation by just don't allow user to select.